# Android Studio java.lang.NoSuchMethodError with dependency

Tags: android, base64, apache-commons, codec

Azure is calling:

```
URLEncoder.encode(encodeBase64String(...
```

which works fine on Android 9 and above. But on old phones I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method encodeBase64String([B)Ljava/lang/String; in class Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)
```

I have tried adding in :

```
implementation "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.14"
```

to build.gradle, but it does not seem to have an effect. What is the usual way to handle it when a class you didn't write that is part of an external SDK, is calling a method old phones don't support?

Answer (score 0):

You should try with below code:

```
String encodedString = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bytes));
```

Comment: The problem is the code is called in the Azure SDK. So I can't actually edit where it's called. So I need some way of getting Android to look at `commons-codec:1.4`, which on Android <=8, it does not seem to be able to do. The inbuilt 1.1 version in Android overrides anything I put in build.gradle